# Maximum link width (link capability) of a pcie card (Intel X710 x8) doesn't show properly

Tags: pci-express, pci

Maximum link width (link capability) of a pcie card (Intel X710 x8) doesn't show properly on X2 or x4 pcie slot. In datasheet of Intel X710 it is mentioned that "The X710/XXV710/XL710 supports a maximum link width of x8, x4, or x1." so does that mean if this card is placed on a x2 slot then it is supposed to show maximum link width as x1? or it should show x8 which card does? Does maximum link width of a pcie card can vary based on the slot width it is placed on?
here max linked width is link capability, this is nothing to do the negotiated link width which is link status.

understanding is link width capability is RO register but with this card it is seen that link capability is changing based on the slot it is placed on.
This is Intel Gen3 card and this not seeing this issue with other intel's Gen2 cards.